# How to scan a file in a different directory in java?

Tags: java, file, directory, java.util.scanner

How do you scan a file with java that isn't in the directory the java file is in?

For example: The java file is located at "C:\Files\JavaFiles\test.java" However, the file I want to scan is located at "C:\Data\DataPacket99\data.txt"

Note: I've already tried putting another java file in the "C:\Data" directory and using the test.java file as a class, but it doesn't work. It still tries to scan from the "C:\Files\JavaFiles" Directory.

Comment: java IO is covered quite a bit here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: are you using relative or absolute path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using an absolute path instead of a relative.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Data\\DataPacket99\\data.txt");
```

Then you can write code that accesses that file object, using a InputStream or similar.

Comment: I think you should escape the slashes; c:\\data\\DataPacket99\\data.txt

Comment: You definitely don't want to be using backslashes as pathname separators in a Java String!

Comment: Escape or, better yet, use forward slashes.

Comment: Unless it's always expected to be in the same directory, a file chooser would probably be a better approach to use than hard coding an absolute path. Just use a file chooser and user the resulting handle for the file to open.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **absolute paths** in java.io stuff. Thus not `new File("data.txt")`, but `new File("C:/Data/DataPacket99/data.txt")`. Otherwise it will be relative to the current working directory which may not per-se be the same in all environments or the one you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

You could use `File file = new File("C:/Data/DataPacket99/data.txt");` but it might make your life easier in the future to use a [file chooser dialog](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) if at any point the user will have to enter a file path.

Comment: Oh dang, awesome (for the file chooser dialog). Thanks _wdh!

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
File file = new File("../../Data/DataPacket99/data.txt");
```