# How to open file in another directory in java?

Tags: java, file, directory

How to open a file that is not present in the current directory but in another directory. For example, I have a folder F:/test and my file is in F:/test/test2/doit.txt and D:/test3/doit2.txt

What to enter in path in parameter while making File object as follows :

```
File f = new File("/test2/doit.txt");
```

Comment: have you googled it before posting here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scan a file in a different directory in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007503/how-to-scan-a-file-in-a-different-directory-in-java)

Comment: put the complete filename

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Irrespective of which operating system, a file for example, demo.txt can be accessed like

```
File file = new File("/d:/user/demo.txt");
```

in Windows where the file is at `D:\user\` and

```
File file = new File("/usr/demo.txt");
```

in `*nix` or `*nux`where the file is at `/usr/`

Also, a file if wanted to be accessed relatively can be done as (considering the Windows example) :

Suppose I am in the songs directory in D: like:

```
D:/
|
|---songs/
|   |
|   |---Main.java
|
|---user/
    |
    |---demo.txt
```

and the code is inside Main.java, then the following code works.

```
File file = new File("../user/demo.txt");
```

Comment: you didn't escape slashes in File() constructor

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are running your program from F:/test you should use something like:

```
File f = new File("./test2/doit.txt");
```

Using hardcoded absolute paths isn't a good idea - your program might not work when user has different directory structure.

Comment: @NickJ explained on the accepted answer.  If you cannot understand the comment, perhaps you should (do a bit of searching &) ask a new question.

Comment: I've added more informations.

@Andrew Thompson: The path is correct assuming that you're running program from D:/test and file location is D:/test/test2/doit.txt.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : I was actually directing Pawel to include the reson for his claims

Answer (score 0):

File inside of a project can be open as:

```
       File file = new File(path);
```

or

```
       File file = new File(./path);
```

where **path** is relative path from the project.

For example, when the project name is **test** and the file with name **fileName** is inside the **test** project:

```
      File file = new File("fileName");
```

or

```
      File file = new File("./fileName");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the code below on Windows OS:

```
reader = new FileReader ("C:/Users/user/Desktop/java/test.txt");
```

Comment: Ok, so the paths need to be absolute rather than relative in java.io. Thankx

Comment: The trouble with expressing the path like that, it makes sure that the application can only run on Windows. Java is supposed to be cross platform. Linux doesn't have a C: drive.

Comment: Now I can read it, this is a poor answer. The OP should figure how to work with relative directories.  Also, don't add salutations and sigs. into answers (or questions).  As comments, they are noise.  As part of a Q or A, really irritating noise.